# SageMaker Estimator use_spot_instances causes Invalid MaxWaitTimeInSeconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, spot-instances

[Managed Spot Training: Save Up to 90% On Your Amazon SageMaker Training Jobs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/managed-spot-training-save-up-to-90-on-your-amazon-sagemaker-training-jobs/) says:

> Setting it up is extremely simple, as it should be when working with a fully-managed service:
>
> - If you’re using the console, just switch the feature on.
> - If you’re working with the Amazon SageMaker SDK, **just set the train_use_spot_instances to true** in the Estimator constructor.

[SageMaker SDK sagemaker.estimator.Estimator](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html#sagemaker.estimator.Estimator) says:

> - use_spot_instances (bool) –
>   Specifies whether to use SageMaker Managed Spot instances for training. If enabled then the max_wait arg should also be set.
> - max_wait (int) –
>   Timeout in seconds waiting for spot training instances (default: None). After this amount of time Amazon SageMaker will stop waiting for Spot instances to become available (default: None).

As per the documentations, run below.

```
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlow


estimator = TensorFlow(
    entry_point="fashion_mnist_training.py",
    source_dir="src",
    metric_definitions=metric_definitions,
    hyperparameters=hyperparameters,
    role=role,
    input_mode='File',
    framework_version="2.3.1",
    py_version="py37",
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge",
    use_spot_instances=True,
    max_wait= 23 * 60 * 60, 
    base_job_name=base_job_name,
    checkpoint_s3_uri=checkpoint_s3_uri,
    model_dir=False  # To avoid duplicate 'model_dir' command line argument
)
```

However, error is caused.

```
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateTrainingJob operation: Invalid MaxWaitTimeInSeconds. It must be present and be greater than or equal to MaxRuntimeInSeconds
```

Answer (score 2):

Another AWS SageMaker incorrect documentation. **just set the train_use_spot_instances to true** in the Estimator constructor is not enough.

[Managed Spot Training: Save Up to 90% On Your Amazon SageMaker Training Jobs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/managed-spot-training-save-up-to-90-on-your-amazon-sagemaker-training-jobs/):

> Setting it up is extremely simple, as it should be when working with a fully-managed service:
>
> - If you’re using the console, just switch the feature on.
> - If you’re working with the Amazon SageMaker SDK, **just set the train_use_spot_instances to true** in the Estimator constructor.

`MaxWaitTimeInSeconds` is required to be equal or greater than `MaxRuntimeInSeconds`.

[SageMaker API StoppingCondition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_StoppingCondition.html)

> #### MaxRuntimeInSeconds
>
> The maximum length of time, in seconds, that a training or compilation job can run.
>
> #### MaxWaitTimeInSeconds
>
> The maximum length of time, in seconds, that a managed Spot training job has to complete. It is **the amount of time spent waiting for Spot capacity plus the amount of time the job can run. It must be equal to or greater than MaxRuntimeInSeconds**. If the job does not complete during this time, Amazon SageMaker ends the job.

## Fix

```
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlow


estimator = TensorFlow(
    entry_point="fashion_mnist_training.py",
    source_dir="src",
    metric_definitions=metric_definitions,
    hyperparameters=hyperparameters,
    role=role,
    input_mode='File',
    framework_version="2.3.1",
    py_version="py37",
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge",
    use_spot_instances=True,
    max_wait= 23 * 60 * 60, 
    max_run = 24 * 60 * 60,     <----------
    base_job_name=base_job_name,
    checkpoint_s3_uri=checkpoint_s3_uri,
    model_dir=False 
)
```

## Related

[SageMaker Managed Spot Training with Object Detection algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58177548/sagemaker-managed-spot-training-with-object-detection-algorithm)

Comment: `max_wait= 23 * 60 * 60` and `max_run = 24 * 60 * 60 - is should be the other way around, right? `max_wait` should be greater than `max_run`.

Answer (score 0):

[The official AWS Managed Spot Training Link is here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-managed-spot-training.html)

It clearly address the following:

> Set `EnableManagedSpotTraining` to `True` and specify the `MaxWaitTimeInSeconds`. `MaxWaitTimeInSeconds` must be larger than `MaxRuntimeInSeconds`.